# Unable to connect to db using node-mssql

Tags: sql-server, jasmine, webdriver-io

Using webdriverio with jasmine framework. Need to connect to a database and I'm using node-mssql to do that.

```
var sql = require('mssql');

sql.connect("mssql://username:password@localhost/database").then(function() {
    new sql.Request().query('select * from mytable').then(function(recordset) {
        console.dir(recordset);
    }).catch(function(err) {
        // ... query error checks 
    });
});
```

Above code is giving me error: "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): ConnectionError: Failed to connect to undefined:1433 - connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:1433
(node:24585) DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code."

I tried without the promises since the code in webdriverio is asynchronous and promises might not work correctly:

```
var connection = sql.connect(config); //config has all the parameters
  var request = new sql.Request();
  request.query('select * from myTable');
```

The error is: "query is undefined"

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you established that you can connect to the SQL Server using client tools such as SQL Server Management Studio and UDL's? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/farukcelik/2007/12/31/basics-first-udl-test/

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the npm request package or the npm request-promise package? I ran into similar issues using the promise version.  What version of node are you using? The latest stable version supports native JavaScript Promises that you can use to handle your async code. I will update this answer in the morning with some sample code using native promise implementation and the request package. Also depending where your async code block is will help determine the answer.. is it in an jasmine 'it' block or in the conf file or somewhere else?